# Adaptar script que usa checkbox para radio

Tags: javascript, html, input

Bom dia, tenho o seguinte código:

```js
function exibe() {
  var tipo = "${mainForm.tipo}";
  var man_tipo = "${mainForm.man_tipo}";


  if ((man_tipo == 'B' && tipo.search('V').toFixed(0) < 0)) {

    if (document.form_folhatd_teste.teste.checked) {

      document.getElementById('pressao_min').style.display = '';
      document.getElementById('pressao_max').style.display = '';
      document.getElementById('vazao_min').style.display = '';
      document.getElementById('vazao_max').style.display = '';
    } else {
      document.getElementById('pressao_min').style.display = 'none';
      document.getElementById('pressao_max').style.display = 'none';
      document.getElementById('vazao_min').style.display = 'none';
      document.getElementById('vazao_max').style.display = 'none';
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<td>
  <input type="checkbox" value="true" name="teste" id="teste" <#if (folhaTDMecanicoForm.lub_forcada)>checkbox</#if>onclick="javascript: exibe();">
</td>
```

Que faz o seguinte: Quando o usuário clica no checkbok, abre uma div com uma série de campos. Até aí tudo certo e funcionando. Porém, preciso que ao invés de `type="checkbox"` tenha `type="radio"` .Vejam o HTML abaixo.

```html
<td>
  Quando selecionado não abre nada
  <input type="radio" value="nao_abri" name="teste" id="teste">
</td>
<td>
  Quando selecionada abre a div 1
  <input type="radio" value="abri1" name="teste" id="teste" <#if (folhaTDTesteForm.teste)>checked</#if>onclick="javascript: exibe();">
</td>
<td>
  Quando selecionada abre a div 2
  <input type="radio" value="abri2" name="teste" id="teste" <#if (folhaTDTesteForm.teste)>checked</#if>onclick="javascript: exibe();">
</td>
```

Como posso adaptar o script acima para funcionar com o `type="radio"`?

Comment: O que exatamente não funciona ao trocar tipo?

Comment: Quando troco o type='checkbox' para type='radio', oscript nao funciona mais. Ou seja a div que abri não abre mais.

Answer (score 3):

@Jessi, realizei alguns testes aqui, me pareceu está funcionando normal:

Como não sei que valores você está atribuindo a tipo e man_tipo, coloquei valores fixos.

Então? este é o comportamento esperado?

```js
var checkbox = document.querySelectorAll("[name='teste']");
var pressao_min = document.getElementById('pressao_min')
var pressao_max = document.getElementById('pressao_max')
var vazao_min = document.getElementById('vazao_min')
var vazao_max = document.getElementById('vazao_max')

var tipo = "Bola";
var man_tipo = "B";

for (var indice in checkbox) {
    checkbox[indice].onclick = function () {   
        if ((man_tipo == 'B' && tipo.search('V').toFixed(0) < 0)) {            
            var display = this.dataset.abrir == "true" ? "" : "none";
            console.log(display);
            pressao_min.style.display = display;
            pressao_max.style.display = display;
            vazao_min.style.display = display;
            vazao_max.style.display = display;
        }
    }
}
```

```html
<input type="radio" data-abrir="false" name="teste" id="teste1"  />
<label for="teste1" >Não Exibir</label>
<input type="radio" data-abrir="true" name="teste" id="teste2" checked />
<label for="teste2" >Exibir</label>
<input type="radio" data-abrir="true" name="teste" id="teste3" />
<label for="teste3" >Exibir</label>

<div>
    <span id="pressao_min" >pressao_min</span>
</div>
<div>
    <span id="pressao_max" >pressao_max</span>
</div>
<div>
    <span id="vazao_min" >vazao_min</span>
</div>
<div>
    <span id="vazao_max" >vazao_min</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Arrumei usando o mesmo script, com agumas alterações.

```js
function exibe(){
 var tipo="${mainForm.tipo}";
 var man_tipo="${mainForm.man_tipo}";
 
 if ((man_tipo=='B' && tipo.search('V').toFixed(0)<0)){ 
  
  if ( document.getElementById("teste1").checked ||  document.getElementById("teste2").checked){
   document.getElementById('pressao_min').style.display='';
   document.getElementById('pressao_max').style.display='';
   document.getElementById('vazao_min').style.display='';
   document.getElementById('vazao_max').style.display=''; 
   
  }else {
   document.getElementById('pressao_min').style.display='none';
   document.getElementById('pressao_max').style.display='none';
   document.getElementById('vazao_min').style.display='none';
   document.getElementById('vazao_max').style.display='none';  
  }  
 }
}
```

Comment: É interresante que você armazene os seus objetos DOM em variaveis, como citado no seguinte link: http://developer.nokia.com/community/wiki/JavaScript_Performance_Best_Practices#Cache_DOM_values_into_variables